# Помогите написать код программы которая создаёт пользовательские аккаунты

Tags: python, python-3.x

Это должно выглядеть так:

Ваше пользовательское имя:

*далее*

Ваш  код-пароль:

*Далее программа сохраняет аккаунт и запрашивает данные для нового аккаунта*

*Но тут есть проблема - если закрыть программу и запустить заново ,то она забудет аккаунты созданные ранее, как это исправить*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохраняй данные в бд или файлик

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html - работа с файлами python 3


но лучше, думаю, пользователей в бд хранить